# How to Make This Layout (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So, i'm new into flutter. And i want to make something similar like the image below. Help guys i know nothing *sad.[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G60GL.png)

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and where you need specific help

Comment: i don't know how to put the image, name, text, etc inside the box. Sorry I can't tell very specific since I know nothing about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use ListTile Widget try below code hope it help to you

```
Card(
            child: ListTile(
              leading: Container(
                width: 50.0,
                height: 50.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black87),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                      'https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/495-4953926_admin-icon-png-white-clipart-png-download-black.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
              title: Text('JULE S'),
              subtitle: Text(
                  'Love this product the smell color and everything are just lovely'),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.person),
            ),
          ),
```

your screen like [image]